# logstash maintaining the order in which data is read

Tags: logstash

I have a single logstash instance and reading data from multiple files. I want to maintain the order in which data is updated in Elasticsearch as the _id field is the key.

So if there are two records in the input file with same key, it has to be updated in order.

How do enforce ordering from a source in logstash?

```
Input file 1:
Key = A1 , Data = abc , time=5:51 PM
Key = B1 , Data = efg , time=5:52 PM
Key = C1 , Data = hij , time=5:53 PM

Input file 2:
Key = A1 , Data = klm, time=5:50 PM
```

This will be read by two threads in logstash.

If there are two filter threads which formats the data.

Output goes to elastics search with _id:

```
output {
  elasticsearch {
   embedded => true
   index => "samples6"
   index_type => "sample"
   document_id => "%{Key}"
 }    
}
```

How to ensure that Key=A1 has Data=abc not "klm".

Comment: Do you have any code you can show us? Or an example of what you are using to do this?

Comment: I am looking for the feasibility in architecture before trying this out. If multiple threads in filter can't maintain order in logstash, i ahve to write something custom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data that needs to be processed in order is read from different files there's no way of doing this since Logstash doesn't maintain an ordered queue of events. If you have more than one filter worker (i.e. start Logstash with `-w`/`--filterworkers` greater than one) there's no order guarantee even if you read from a single file.

You'll have to write something yourself to get the ordering right. Perhaps [Apache Samza](http://samza.incubator.apache.org/) could be of use.

Comment: The data within a file will be processed in order in logstash for sure no matter how many filter threads are allocated?

Comment: No, if you want contents within a file to be processed in order you need exactly one filter worker. I'll clarify.

Comment: Thanks. May be I'll start with multiple logstash instances invoked per file /rdbms with one single filter thread.